# Question regarding Bonferroni correction

Tags: statistics

Prove the following version of the Bonferroni inequality-
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_i\right)\ge1-\sum_{i=1}^kP(A_i^c)$$

When creating simultaneous confidence interval, what are $A_i$ and $A_i^c$?

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

$$1-\sum P(A_i^c)\leq 1-P\left(\bigcup A_i^c\right)=P(X)-P\left(\bigcup A_i^c\right)=P\left(\left[\bigcup A_i^c\right]^c\right)=P\left(\bigcap A_i^{c^c}\right)=P\left(\bigcap A_i\right)$$